# Visual Studio - Test Automation nUnit - possibility to see the progress of the test execution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automated-tests, nunit

I just started in my Team to work with Visual Studio using nUnit framework (C#) for the test automation. Before I used (for couple of years) Selenium, jUnit framework (Java), Cucumber.  I used to be able to see the progress of the test execution while the test is running step after the step.
This would be achieved by adding statement: **stepNotifications = true**, into the test runner file.

I.e.

[image]

it would also be very easy to see where a failures happened:

I.e.

[image]

Now in the Test Explorer in Visual Studio while the test is running I can see that it is being executed and which test is being executed:

[image]

but I can not see where the test at that particular moment.
Is it possible to get the visibility of on which step (method) the test is running at the current moment, something like in Selenium, jUnit I had before?